# Error find last 30 minutes using dblink

Tags: postgresql

```
INSERT INTO ip_cpu_mn(datetime, resource_id, ipaddress,cpu_utilization)
SELECT cpu_mn.datetime, resource_id, ipaddress, cpu_utilization
FROM dblink('host=10.0.32.175 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=TNPM_EXT','SELECT datetime, resource_id, ipaddress,cpu_utilization  FROM ext_ip.cpu_mn WHERE datetime >=(now() - interval '30 minutes')')
AS cpu_mn(datetime timestamp without time zone, resource_id numeric(10,0), ipaddress character varying(20), sysname character varying(100), cpu_utilization numeric(6,2))
```

Hi running above query and get below error :

> psql.bin:/home/samila/SQL_SMZ/ip_cpu_mn1.sql:15: ERROR:  syntax error
>   at or near "30" LINE 6: ...xt_ip.cpu_mn WHERE datetime >= (now() -
>   interval '30 minute'...

Anyone can help me ? i have tried many ways , still got error at the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suspect is a single quote(`'`) in your query(`ERROR: syntax error at or near "30"` its really clear),You need to add two quotes here `now() - interval ''30 minutes''`

```
INSERT INTO ip_cpu_mn(datetime, resource_id, ipaddress,cpu_utilization)
SELECT cpu_mn.datetime, resource_id, ipaddress, cpu_utilization
FROM dblink('host=10.0.32.175 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=TNPM_EXT','SELECT datetime, resource_id, ipaddress,cpu_utilization  FROM ext_ip.cpu_mn WHERE datetime >=(now() - interval ''30 minutes'')')
AS cpu_mn(datetime timestamp without time zone, resource_id numeric(10,0), ipaddress character varying(20), sysname character varying(100), cpu_utilization numeric(6,2))
```